# Mercurial: make `hg log` not show files?

Tags: mercurial, verbosity

I'm (ab)using Mercurial to manage thousands of files that change often, but I'd like to be able to view the log (`hg log`) without having my term filled with all of the filenames that changed on each commit.  `hg log -q` is a little *too* quiet, since I need to see the descriptions.  Is there a flag I'm missing for `hg log`?

Comment: hg log does not show list of files in my installation. What version of hg are you using?

Comment: If `hg log` doesn't show the changed files you can do `hg log --verbose` or `hg log -v`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds as if you might have the `verbose` flag turned on.  You can check by running `hg showconfig` and looking for a line like `ui.verbose=true`.

There are a few ways you can fix it:

- remove that line from the offending configuration file (Mercurial can use several, and they vary by OS: use `hg help config` to list the possibilities).
- override the flag in your repository's `.hg\hgrc` or your private Mercurial configuration (`Mercurial.ini` or `~/.hgrc`): add the following lines to it:

  `[ui]

  verbose=false`
- clear the verbose flag on the commandline: `hg log --config ui.verbose=false`.